# which app shall I install on google cloud platform for wordpress multisite woocommerce and which engine?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have Wordpress multisite installation on sub-directory. It is an e-commerce website and I am using google cloud platform to host it. I want to know which app shall i install and which engine shall i use like kubernetes or compute engine. Moreover if i install multisite wordpress then will it have sub-domain or sub-directory by default or i will get the option to chose. how much ram my website requires and what is the bandwidth offered by google cloud.

I tried 512 mb ram and godaddy hosting which was not good. with zero traffic they notified 100 entry processes and 100% ram. where as my website was only in development mode.

Answer (score 3):

There are some options in the GCP Marketplace for Wordpress multi-site hosting, this is a one click deployment, it will create the VM and the necessary configuration for you wordpress start working in GCP.

Once created you can personalize your websites and configure Wordpress according to your needs, there are two options available:

1- The first option is a solution from One-click to deploy and as you may see in [1] the VM tier of VM (this means the resources) that creates is 1 vCPU + 3.75 GB memory (n1-standard-1), this is usually enough for websites with no much traffic.

2- The second option is a solution from Bitnami [2] with a certified and updated version of wordpress for multi-sites, however this version of the marketplace uses the lowest tier of VM 1 shared vCPU + 1.7 GB memory (g1-small) this has less resources so the processing capacity will be lower for your VM.

You may see according to the tier of the VM is the pricing, you may consult [3] for details of the tiers offered by Google Cloud Platform.

Also, notice that doesn’t matter which option you choose, if you need more resources in your VM you may update the VMs resources once it was already created, you can consult [4] for steps to change the VM type in GCP.

E.g. Let’s say you choose the bitnami solution that uses the lowest tier, while you develop your sites and configure your wordpress the best is to keep it low because it will cost more if you have more resources even if you’re not using them. But when your sites go live, you can change the machine type in order to have more processing capacity and according to the behavior of your sites you may increase or decrease the resources of your VM at any point, just notice that the VM has to be stopped to do such (this means your sites will be down for a few minutes while the operation is finished).

[1] https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress-multisite

[2] https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress-multisite

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#standard_machine_types

[4] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type